# Message navigates to websites provided by cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that gathers data through SQL queries from a database that displays on a website. The queries gather data that is present and displays in a table which provide URL and time posted (these are columns: URL and Time), with this information I have a cell (B25 B28 and others), which uses a =countif formula to gather all the items that are in the table and which ones are past a certain time.

Example:

```
=COUNTIFS(table_name[URL Column Name],"Items underneath said Column",table_name[Time Column],">"&NOW()-0.167)
```

I'm trying to create a VBA script in the worksheet that has this information, launch the URL provided from the cell this formula reads, or display a list if there are more than 1 item over the allotted time. Ultimately I need a message box to display the URL.

So far, I have this as my VBA code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    Dim lResponse As Long
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Me.Range("D25, D28, D31, D34, D37").Value > 0 Then
        lResponse = MsgBox("my message for yes or no?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo,     "box title")
        If lResponse = vbYes Then
            ie.Navigate(" & Me.Range &").Value
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What does it do so far? What exactly do you need help with? Are there any errors in your code? If so, where?

Comment: `Me.Range("D25, D28, D31, D34, D37").Value > 0` only tests the value of `D25`. The other ranges are superfluous when using this construct. Do you want the condition to include each of those ranges having a value larger than zero?

Comment: Hey Tom, well right now all it does is highlight "Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")" I get a Run-time error '-2147467259. I'm wanting validation if this code appears to be correct or if so what can be improved. Any help is awesome.

Comment: @Excel Hero, Yes that is exactly what I want to do. Include those other cells in the condition

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I don't know if it will help but there is.

```
MyVariable = Range("D25, D28, D31, D34, D37")

for each Mycell in MyVariable
    if MyCell.Value > 0 then
    ..... 'your code
next Mycelll
```